# Return date automatically in R

Tags: r

is there a way to write a command in R that automatically returns today's date exactly one year ago in R? I know that to return today's date I can use `Sys.Date()`, just trying to do the same to return the same day one year ago

Comment: `Sys.Date() - 365`

Comment: If necessary, install and load the ```lubridate``` package and try this ```ymd(Sys.Date()) - years(1)```